# For all $x\not =0 \in\mathbb{R}^m$ and $h\in\mathbb{R}^m$, who is $\xi'(x)\cdot h$?

Tags: integration, analysis, derivatives, inner-products

If $f,g:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ are differentiable with $f\in C^1$ and $\xi:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where
$$\xi(x)=\langle g(x),\int_0^{|x|}f(tx)dt\rangle,$$
with $|x|=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$, then for all $x\not =0 \in\mathbb{R}^m$ and $h\in\mathbb{R}^m$, who is $\xi'(x)\cdot h$?

I don't know how to proceed with the second term. What I've done is:

$\forall x\not =0 \in\mathbb{R}^m$ and $h\in\mathbb{R}^m$,

$$\xi'(x)\cdot h=\lim_{w\to 0}{\frac{\xi(x+wh)-\xi(x)}{w}}=$$
$$=\lim_{w\to 0}\left\langle\frac{g(x+wh)-g(x)}{w},\frac{\int_{0}^{|x+wh|}f(tx+twh)dt-\int_{0}^{|x|}f(tx)dt}{w}\right\rangle=$$
$$=\left\langle g'(x)\cdot h,\lim_{w\to0}\left(\frac{\int_{0}^{|x+wh|}f(tx+twh)dt-\int_{0}^{|x|}f(tx)dt}{w}\right)\right\rangle$$

And after that, how could I establish that
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{r_\xi(h)}{|h|}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\xi(x+h)-\xi(x)-\xi'(x)\cdot h}{|h|}=0?$$

Comment: Maybe you should use different $t$ than the one in integration. Use other notation $s$ for example. (In that case you won't get the confusing expression with $t^2$). Or maybe I see something wrong.

Comment: @kolobokish you're right. I'm gonna fix it.

Comment: It seem to me that will help. ;)

Comment: @kolobokish I think it's right now.

Comment: One more question and probably i could answer the question.  What do you mean by $g'(x)$. (Gradient ? or something else?). And what is the integral of $f(tx)$?

Comment: @kolobokish once g is differentiable, then $$g'(x)\cdot h=\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{g(x+wh)-g(x)}{w}.$$

Comment: @kolobokish As g is differentiable, $g'(x)$ is a linear aplication such that $g'(x):\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and you can see as $g':\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: @kolobokish About the integral of $f(tx)$, I really don't know.  That is my problem, but I think some Theorem or a result could help here, because I don't know the face of that integral. I think that partial derivatives are required for that statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems something is wrong.

Lets try to calculate the derivative of $\xi$ use inner product linearity.

$$\xi(x+wh)-\xi(x) = \langle g(t+wh), \int_{0}^{|x+wh|}f(t(x+wh))dt \rangle -\langle g(x), \int_{0}^{|x|}f(tx)dt \rangle$$.

Lets add and subtract $\langle g(x), \int_{0}^{|x+wh|}f(t(x+wh))dt\rangle$.

We will get

$$\xi(x+wh)-\xi(x) = \langle g(t+wh), \int_{0}^{|x+wh|}f(t(x+wh))dt \rangle - \langle g(x), \int_{0}^{|x+wh|}f(t(x+wh))dt\rangle+ \langle g(x), \int_{0}^{|x+wh|}f(t(x+wh))dt\rangle-\langle g(x), \int_{0}^{|x|}f(tx)dt \rangle$$

Combining the first two and the last twoyou will have

$$\xi(x+wh)-\xi(x) = \langle g(t+wh)-g(x), \int_{0}^{|x+wh|}f(t(x+wh))dt \rangle + \langle g(x), \int_{0}^{|x+wh|}f(t(x+wh))dt-\int_{0}^{|x|}f(tx)dt \rangle$$.

Dividing by $w$ and taking limit you'll get

$$\xi(x) \cdot h =  \lim_{w \to 0} \left(\langle \frac{g(t+wh)-g(x)}{w}, \int_{0}^{|x+wh|}f(t(x+wh))dt \rangle + \langle g(x), \frac{\int_{0}^{|x+wh|}f(t(x+wh))dt-\int_{0}^{|x|}f(tx)dt}{w} \rangle \right)$$.

So we get

$$ \xi'(x) \cdot h = \langle g'(x)\cdot h, \int_{0}^{|x|}f(tx)dt\rangle + \langle g(x), \int_{0}^{|x|}f'(tx)\cdot th \ dt \rangle$$.

---

The derivation of the integral part
We consider this

$$ \lim_{w \to 0} \left(\langle g(x), \frac{\int_{0}^{|x+wh|}f(t(x+wh))dt-\int_{0}^{|x|}f(tx)dt}{w} \rangle \right)$$

As the first component has no $w$, we let's just look at

$$\lim_{w \to 0}  \frac{\int_{0}^{|x+wh|}f(t(x+wh))dt-\int_{0}^{|x|}f(tx)dt}{w} =\lim_{w \to 0}  \frac{\int_{0}^{|x+wh|}f(t(x+wh))dt-\int_{0}^{|x|}f(t(x+wh))dt + \int_{0}^{|x|}f(t(x+wh))dt -\int_{0}^{|x|}f(tx)dt}{w} $$

Let's combine first two terms and last two terms.

$$\lim_{w \to 0}   \frac{\int_{|x|}^{|x+wh|}f(t(x+wh))dt + \int_{0}^{|x|}(f(t(x+wh))-f(tx))dt}{w} $$

In the second term interval of integration does not depend on $w$, so we can just differentiate under the sign of integration.

The first integral will surely converge to 0 as $w \to 0$, as the region of integration will become a point. But how fast?

As the integral of upper bound
We can rewrite

$$\lim_{w \to 0}   \frac{\int_{|x|}^{|x+wh|}f(t(x+wh))dt }{w}= f(|x|(x))\cdot h$$.

(So sorry I was wrong in my calculations).

So the correct answer should be

$$ \xi'(x) \cdot h = \langle g'(x)\cdot h, \int_{0}^{|x|}f(tx)dt\rangle + \left\langle g(x), \  f(|x|(x))\cdot h + \int_{0}^{|x|}f'(tx)\cdot th \ dt \right\rangle$$.

Comment: OMG, @kolobokish ! As I can see, everything is correct. Just one question. Here:
$$ \xi'(x) \cdot h = \langle g'(x)\cdot h, \int_{0}^{|x|}f(tx)dt\rangle + \langle g(x), \int_{0}^{x}f'(tx)\cdot th \ dt \rangle$$
Is that $x$ or $|x|$ on the integral?

Comment: And thank you! You really helped me. That's not a homework but I really spent too much time on it. <3

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for that typo. It should really be $|x|$.

Comment: "(The derivation of last term is a little more sophisticated, but simply plus the integral with the same bounds but with f(tx) and subtract one and you will get the answer)."

I think I didn't get it. :'(

Comment: Let me ask something. If I prove that if $U$ is and open set of $\mathbb{R}^m$, $\xi(x)=\langle f(x),g(x)\rangle$, where $\xi:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with and $f,g:U\subset \mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ then
$$\xi'(x)\cdot h=\langle f'(x)\cdot h,g(x)\rangle + \langle f(x),g'(x)\cdot h\rangle,$$
I can avoid all of those manipulations and it rests to show what is 
$g'(x)\cdot h$, which in this case $g(x)=\int_{0}^{|x|}f(tx)dt$.

Comment: So many questions and I really want to rock it :D. If $f$ is $C^1$, then is $\int_{0}^{|x|}f(tx)dt$  differentiable?

Comment: About you previous question. It seem to me yes. (No much difference between usual differentiation of product function, and inner product). (Probably you could if that was only function dependence upon $x$, but here you have some sort of this function $h(x, |x|)$, or functional depending on $x$. Here is the point i'm not sure about. )

Comment: Hmmmmmm got it.

Comment: About the differentiability of the integral, I don't know. I see no problems with that. (If $f$ were not n-vector valued, i would surely answer yes. But here I don't understand what is the meaning of integral.

Comment: For example If we regard this like integral of the following form (which I assumed), everything should be ok. $\int_{0}^{|x|}f(tx)dt  = (\int_{0}^{|x|}f_{1}(tx) dt, ... , \int_{0}^{|x|}f_{n}(tx) dt)$. (As we used it as a component of scalar product, it seems to me it should be of appropriate dimension). (So it is component-wise integral, in which case you can deal with them as with ordinary vector-valued function, and it component of this function is for sure differentiable).

Comment: Right! Very explanatory. Thanks! I think that only part is missing is: "(The derivation of last term is a little more sophisticated, but simply plus the integral with the same bounds but with f(tx) and subtract one and you will get the answer)." I didn't get it yet. :'(

Comment: Let me add it to the answer.

Comment: You were right. I forgot for a moment that the upper bound still depends on $w$. I corrected my answer. Now I'm sure everything should be correct. (You don't even need to check that $\frac{r(h)}{h} \to 0$, as that is precisely the same procedure).   Are there anyway to check the answer?

Comment: I think it's correct now! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! So I'm able to sleep now. :D